# Leaflet draw delete features with property

Tags: leaflet, geojson, leaflet.draw

Is it possible to delete multiple features from geojson at once by checking property value?

Using for example code below or using Leaflet draw?

```
function deleteArea() {
var layers = featureGroup.getLayers();
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {

        if (layers[i].feature.properties.N == 1)
{
        "DELETE?" layer[i];
        };
}
};
```

I have big map and some markers have property: feature.properties.N=1. I can delete them using leaflet draw clicking one by one because I changed marker to red for those layers. But it takes some time.. Is it possible to to this at once?

[image]

Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can simply remove the markers from the map / featuregroup with `layer.removeFrom(featureGroup)`

```
function deleteArea() {
var layers = featureGroup.getLayers();
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        if (layers[i].feature.properties.N == 1){
            layer[i].removeFrom(featureGroup);
        };
}
};
```

PS: I prefer to use [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) because it is more modern and is still being supported and gets new features